# Equivalent of form requests in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

Form requests are not only sent to the server, but they also redirect the user to the given resource and with the given method. I want to have the same feature in AJAX.

For example, I want the equivalent of the request sent by this form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/resource">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I don't want a redirect in the callback method of AJAX like that:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<script>
function submit() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/resource",
    type: "POST",
    success: function() {
      window.location.replace("/resource")
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

`window.location.replace(...)` only sends GET requests, but I also want to be able to send POST requests like with forms.
How should I do?

Comment: so why don't you just use a form?

Comment: The redirect is a GET request, you don't POST to a url and then do POST to the redirected url

Comment: @KarstenKoop For my case, I want to have buttons inside of a form that send AJAX POST requests to another url than that of the form action, and I cannot do forms nested in forms as it is forbidden.

Comment: @Musa I know that redirects are only GET requests, but how do you name the change of page in POST then? Sending a request to a resource and redirecting to it afterward sounds stupid, but that's the closest I can get to simulating a form request in AJAX.

Comment: So you want to send an ajax POST request to a url but also navigate to it as well(or after)? But its not working because that url expects a POST request?

Comment: Not after, at the same time, just like form requests. To be more clear, how can I see in the browser the page returned by the route `POST /resource` but without using a form?

Comment: have u considered changing the forms action dynamically when a button is pressed and then use java script to submit the form?

Comment: You know, each button in the from can have its own url to submit to.

Comment: @RyDog That's a very twisted solution that would work in certain cases but not in mine, because if I change the action the same data would be sent, but I want some specific data to be sent if I press button 1, and other specific data to be sent if I press button 2@Musa  What are you thinking of?

Comment: It was basically the same idea RyDog had but implemented via HTML rather than JavaScript

Comment: @Musa  was hinting using the 'formaction' attribute on the submit button, which would work to send the form to a different action url depending on what button you click.  I have an idea that might work ... ill compose an answer for you

Comment: @RyDog You were talking earlier about submitting the form via Javascript. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using formaction**

Alright so in this solution, we use formaction on submit buttons to decide where the form will go and we use event listeners for each submit button to disable the fields you don't want. This will let you submit the form to different locations and depending on what button you click it will send different inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//event listener for first submit
    $("#submit-1").on("click",function(event){
          //disable inputs you don't want to send
         $("#input-2").prop('disabled', true);
          
    });
 //event listener for second submit
    $("#submit-2").on("click",function(event){
          //disable inputs you don't want to send
         $("#input-1").prop('disabled', true);
          
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-1" action="#" method="post">

<input type="text" name="input-1" id="input-1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="input-2" id="input-2" />
<br/>
<input formaction="reource1" type="submit" name="submit-1" id="submit-1" value="Send Input 1"/>
<br>
<input formaction="reource2" type="submit" name="submit-2" id="submit-2" value="Send Input 2"/>

</form>
```

Let me know if this answers the question.

---

**Alternative Changing form action using JS**

In this solution we change the forms action using JS and then disable the inputs we don't want to send and then force the form to be submitted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //event listener for first submit
  $("#submit-1").on("click", function(event) {
    //disable inputs you don't want to send
    $("#input-2").prop('disabled', true);
    //change form action
    $("#form-1").attr("action", "resource1");

    //submit form
    $("#form-1").submit();
  });
  //event listener for second submit
  $("#submit-2").on("click", function(event) {
    //disable inputs you don't want to send
    $("#input-1").prop('disabled', true);
    //change form action
    $("#form-1").attr("action", "resource2");
    //submit form
    $("#form-1").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-1" action="#" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="input-1" id="input-1" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="input-2" id="input-2" />
  <br/>
  <button id="submit-1" type="button">Send Input 1</button>

  <br>
  <button id="submit-2" type="button">Send Input 2</button>


</form>
```

Comment: That's a good answer for my case (which is how to have two buttons in the same form that do different actions), but it doesn't answer the initial question which is how to do "redirects" in POST. I give you an upvote for the dedication though.

Comment: Note: You were talking in the other thread about submitting a form via Javascript. If it is really possible, it might solve my problem.

Comment: i added  submitting the form using JS to my answer, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes it is, I would have liked your answer to be a bit simpler but that will do :)